# Boundedness of the sequence in Lebesgue space

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Please help me to prove this statement:

If we have $0<\varepsilon<1$, $\frac{1}{m}<\frac{2}{2^{*}}$, where $2^{*}=\frac{2N}{N-2}$, with $N>2$  and $u_{\varepsilon}\geq 0$ satisfies 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left(\int_{\Omega}\left[(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}-1\right]
\right)^{\frac{2}{2^{*}}}&\leq \left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
then, $u_{\varepsilon}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^{r}(\Omega)$.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since 
\begin{equation}
\left[\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}-1\right]^{\frac{2}{2^{*}}}\leq \left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{\frac{1}{m}},
\end{equation}
then, by using the fact that the real function $t\longmapsto t^{2^{*}}$ is increasing on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, we have 
\begin{equation}
\left[\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}-1\right]^{2}\leq \left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{\frac{2^{*}}{m}}.\qquad(2)
\end{equation}

Recalling the real inequality
\begin{equation}
\vert t^{2}-1\vert<\alpha(t-1)^{2}+\frac{1}{\alpha-1},\qquad\forall\alpha>1,\;\forall t\geq 0.
\end{equation}
Applying the above inequality for $t=\frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert}\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}$ (this choice is possible since $u_{\varepsilon}\geq 0$  and $\varepsilon>0$), we get

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\left[\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}-1\right]^{2}
&=\vert\Omega\vert^{2}\left[\left(\frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert}\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)-1\right]^{2}
\\
&>\frac{1}{\alpha}\big|\frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert^{2}}\left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{2}-1\big|-\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}.\qquad(4)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Combining (2) and (4), we deduce that
\begin{equation}
\big|\frac{1}{\vert\Omega\vert^{2}}\left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{2}-1\big|\leq\alpha \left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{\frac{2^{*}}{m}}+\frac{1}{1-\alpha}.\qquad(5)
\end{equation}
(5) implies that
\begin{equation}
\left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{2}\leq\alpha\vert\Omega\vert^{2} \left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{\frac{2^{*}}{m}}+\frac{2-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\vert\Omega\vert^{2}.\qquad(6)
\end{equation}
Since $\frac{1}{m}<\frac{2}{2^{*}}$, then Young's inequality with $p=\frac{2m}{2^{*}}$ and $q=\frac{2m}{2m-2^{*}}$ on the first term on the right-hand side of (6) gives
\begin{equation}
\left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{2}\leq \frac{2^{*}}{2m} \left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{2}+\frac{\alpha^{q}\vert\Omega\vert^{2q}}{q}+\frac{2-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\vert\Omega\vert^{2}.\qquad(7)
\end{equation}
From (7), we deduce that
\begin{equation}
\frac{2m-2^{*}}{2m}\left(\int_{\Omega}(u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon)^{r}\right)^{2}\leq \frac{\alpha^{q}\vert\Omega\vert^{2q}}{q}+\frac{2-\alpha}{1-\alpha}\vert\Omega\vert^{2}.
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
\Vert u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon\Vert_{r}\leq C,
\end{equation}
where C is positive constant independent of $\varepsilon$. Since $0<\varepsilon<1$ and the fact that
\begin{equation}
\big|\Vert u_{\varepsilon}\Vert_{r}-\Vert \varepsilon\Vert_{r}\big|\leq\Vert u_{\varepsilon}+\varepsilon\Vert_{r},
\end{equation}
we deduce that 
\begin{equation}
\Vert u_{\varepsilon}\Vert_{r}\leq C+\Vert\varepsilon\Vert_{r}\leq C+\vert\Omega\vert^{\frac{1}{r}}.
\end{equation}
So, the sequence $u_{\varepsilon}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^{r}(\Omega)$.